# Istio: auth url support in end user authentication

Tags: nginx, oauth-2.0, kubernetes, istio, nginx-ingress

I'm looking to do 3 legged oauth on istio+kubernetes. I did not find a way to route unauthenticated requests to an authentication proxy service which performs the authentication and route the traffic back to the target service. I've done this with [nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md) kubernetes ingress controller using the following annotations -

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url //Auth url that requests will be forwarded to
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin //Sign in page the request is routed to when the above returns 401
```

I did not find equivalent ones in Istio. I've checked the [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.authentication.v1alpha1/) and it says it supports custom auth in addition to jwt, however I did not find any such support.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful [End User Authentication](https://istio.io/help/ops/security/end-user-auth/)

Comment: Thanks @Crou. That does jwt based authentication, but is not capable of performing 3-legged oauth flow and get the token, which is the typical model for protected UI resources.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.
At this point I've figured out the only way to do this is via [EnvoyFilter](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#EnvoyFilter) on istio. This allows us to write a custom [lua filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http_filters/lua_filter) to to route unauthenticated requests to an oauth proxy which can perform 3-legged oauth flow.

The request control flow is

> client --> ingress gateway --> istio-proxy sidecar --> envoy filter --> target

The filter is capable of making http calls and manipulate headers, which fits this requirement.

Edit:
Details about it are [here](https://medium.com/@suman_ganta/openid-authentication-with-istio-a32838adb492).

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit more on your lua filter? thanks